# mark angular form group if controls have value

Tags: angular, forms

Angular form groups has "ng-valid", "ng-touched" etc... But is there a way to check if the controls in a group has value ?

The reason is, that I want to set a checkmark on the group if the child controls has value, and remove it if they don't have values

My form is a dynamic form

```
<div *ngIf="loaded">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let group of objectKeys(globalForm); let index = index">
      <app-question-expand [label]="group" [background]="index % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'">
        {{ form.controls[group].value | json }}
```

on the last line I write some code that gives me

```
{ "Q1-A": false, "Q1-B": "", "Q1-C": "", "Q1-Andet": "" }
```

But somehow I want to evaluate this to a single true false. Does any of the keys have values

Comment: you should add some code that shows what you're after

Comment: updated my question

Comment: is this a validator or something? and also what counts as a value? is false a value? is empty string a value?

Comment: empty string is not a value. Angular makes the object automatic based on form controls. It would be easier if was an array, that was only filled with controls that had a value

Comment: but maybe this is a wrong approach. Maybe Angular has some build in method for checking form groups

Comment: I created a small demo. Is this what you were trying to achieve? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6agem

Comment: hi. It is a bit in the right direction. The logic should be if 1 or more are filled, than show

Comment: changed `.every` to `.some`. try now.

Comment: There is one problem. If you put in a console.log('asd'); It seems the method gets called multiple times.

Comment: @Johansrk I moved the `check` method to be a pipe and I added `trackBy` for the `ngFor`. Try now.

Comment: very very close.. It actually works. There is just one thing. If a control is prefilled, than the "SOME FILLED" message is not shown

Comment: ahh. I fixed it by writting this
 <ng-container *ngIf="item.value.value | check">SOME FILLED</ng-container>

Comment: I want to mark your answer, but can't when it is just a comment

Comment: @Johansrk Nah that's ok, the most important thing that it works now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the kind of simple approach here is just to do this:

```
hasOneValue(fg: FormGroup) {
  return Object.values(fg.controls).some(fc => !!fc.value);
}

{{ hasValue(form.controls[group]) }}
```

but this is kind of a low performance approach given the function call in template that will evaluate on everychange detection cycle for every item in your list. Myself, I'd prefer something that evaluated when it needed to rather than on change detection (ie, when the form values change).  The easiest way to do that is with a validator on your groups:

```
hasNoValues() {
  return (fg: FormGroup) => Object.values(fg.controls).some(fc => !!fc.value) ? null : {hasNoValues: true};
}
```

which you'd assign to your group like:

```
this.formBuilder.group({..}, {validators: [hasNoValues()]})
```

and you could look at it like this:

```
{{ form.controls[group].errors?.hasNoValues }}
```

the potentially undesirable side effect here is that it will mark your form as invalid if there is not at least one value.

If that's unacceptable, You could potentially achieve this in an alternative method using valueChanges in a loop / modifying your objectKeys function:

```
objectKeys(fg: FormGroup) }
   return Object.keys(fg.controls).map(group => {
     const hasValue$ = fg.controls[group].valueChanges.pipe(map(v => Object.values(v).some(v => !!v)));
     return {group, hasValue$};
   });
}
```

now it returns both an array of keys and observables, the catch here, is that since it's building streams, you need to take this function call out of template and just execute it as needed (probably a good idea anyway tbh), so somewhere appropriate you'd add:

```
this.groups = this.objectKeys(this.globalForm);
```

and you'd need to recall that anytime globalForm changes, then simply access by:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups; let index = index">
  <app-question-expand [label]="group.group" [background]="index % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'">
    {{ group.hasValue$ | async }}
```

if globalForm doesn't change often, this is easily the safest and most performant approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer works, but @Eliya Cohen, works even better

Comment: a pipe works in this case but I'm generally careful with creating secretly impure pipes.  It works in this context becaue valueChanges | async always produces a new object and never mutates.  But if you were to use the check pipe on an object that was being mutated, it would fail.

Comment: but again thanks a lot. I have used many hours today, banging my head against the wall. :)

Answer (score 0):

i am using array values so i am did like that..

```
  hasFormValue(fg: FormGroup) {    
    return Object.values(fg.controls).some(fc => Array.isArray(fc.value) ? fc.value.length > 0 : !!fc.value);
  }
```